# rename list of dataframe columns to mimic joined suffixes

Tags: r, list, purrr

I have a list of dataframes:

```
dd <- list()

dd$data <- list(
  ONE = data.frame(inAll = c(1.1,1.2,1.3), inAll_2 = c(1.4,1.5,1.6)),
  TWO = data.frame(inAll = c(2.1,2.2,2.3), inAll_2 = c(2.4,2.5,2.6)),
  THREE = data.frame(inAll = c(3.1,3.2,3.3), inAll_2 = c(3.4,3.5,3.6)),
  FOUR = data.frame(inAll = c(4.1,4.2,4.3), inAll_2 = c(4.4,4.5,4.6)),
  FIVE = data.frame(inAll = c(5.1,5.2,5.3), inAll_2 = c(5.4,5.5,5.6)),
  SIX = data.frame(inAll = c(6.1,6.2,6.3), inAll_2 = c(6.4,6.5,6.6))
)
```

And then reduce those dataframes using suffixes

```
reduce(dd$data, full_join, by = "inAll", suffix = c("_x", "_y"))
```

My desired output is

```
map(dd$data, list())
```

BUT I want the names to be the same as the suffixes in the reduced dataset.

How do I expand on this map function so that I rename the columns in the list to reflect the reduced names?

## PATTERN:

[I tried looking at the join source code for this!] and it looks like all matching but not joined on columns are:

- given _x then _y suffix
- this continues with _x_x and _y_y and so on
- if the number of list items with repeating column no suffix last

*Note that these data frames in my example generally have other columns AND the columns are not always in the same order so I want to avoid anything fragile like matching by index!*

```
new_names <- function(df) {
  # logic about new suffixes somehow
  map(df,list())
}
```

## Desired Output

A list that looks like this:

```
dd$data2 <- list(
  ONE = data.frame(inAll = c(1.1,1.2,1.3), inAll_2_x = c(1.4,1.5,1.6)),
  TWO = data.frame(inAll = c(2.1,2.2,2.3), inAll_2_y = c(2.4,2.5,2.6)),
  THREE = data.frame(inAll = c(3.1,3.2,3.3), inAll_2_x_x = c(3.4,3.5,3.6)),
  FOUR = data.frame(inAll = c(4.1,4.2,4.3), inAll_2_y_y = c(4.4,4.5,4.6)),
  FIVE = data.frame(inAll = c(5.1,5.2,5.3), inAll_2_x_x_x = c(5.4,5.5,5.6)),
  SIX = data.frame(inAll = c(6.1,6.2,6.3), inAll_2_y_y_y = c(6.4,6.5,6.6))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the question - I want to rename the columns, not reduce it, I was using reduce to illustrate how I want to rename my columns using the same logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a repeated character string with `strrep` (from `base R`) for 'x', 'y', `rep`licate it, loop over the `list` column with `map2` and `rename_at` the 2nd column by `paste`ing (`str_c`) the suffix passed

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
n <- ceiling(length(dd$data)/2)
map2(dd$data,  strrep(rep(c('_x', '_y'), n), rep(seq_len(n), each = 2)), ~
             {nm <- .y
               .x %>% 
                 rename_at(vars(inAll_2), ~ str_c(., nm))
     })
#$ONE
#  inAll inAll_2_x
#1   1.1       1.4
#2   1.2       1.5
#3   1.3       1.6

#$TWO
#  inAll inAll_2_y
#1   2.1       2.4
#2   2.2       2.5
#3   2.3       2.6

#$THREE
#  inAll inAll_2_x_x
#1   3.1         3.4
#2   3.2         3.5
#3   3.3         3.6

#$FOUR
#  inAll inAll_2_y_y
#1   4.1         4.4
#2   4.2         4.5
#3   4.3         4.6

#$FIVE
#  inAll inAll_2_x_x_x
#1   5.1           5.4
#2   5.2           5.5
#3   5.3           5.6

#$SIX
#  inAll inAll_2_y_y_y
#1   6.1           6.4
#2   6.2           6.5
#3   6.3           6.6
```